# Does unitary operator on a Hilbert space maps a star cyclic vector to a star cyclic vector?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normal-operator

Let $H$ be a infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $T: H \to H $ be a bounded normal star cyclic operator with star cyclic vector $e$ ( $T$ will be called star cyclic with star cyclic vector $e$ if
$\overline{ span\{T^m T^{*n} e : m,n \in \mathbb N_0\} } =H$ ), then prove or disprove $||TUe||=||Te||$ for any unitary operator $U:H \to H$.

Please help me in this problem, I have counter example in finite dimensional case but not in infinite dimensional case. Either help me proving this or disprove this by giving a counter example.

Thanks in advanced